# Why does Windows date jump a month ahead

Tags: windows, date

We have a few computers that run Windows XP and every now and again they put the date/time one month forward in time.

This just happened again today, putting the date to 20th September 2010. This is causing problems as the software that runs on these PCs date stamps records in a database.

I happens on at least two different computers that I know about, both are at different sites but in the same geological location and use the same ISP.

Both computers are relatively new HP machines (Both purchased this year, but at different times). They both have service pack 3 installed and have the Time Zone set to GMT. The Internet Time Sync is turned on and set to sync with time.windows.com.

I have ran a virus scan on both PCs that showed nothing. What could be causing this?

Comment: You don't happen to double-click the clock to get the calendar up to check on dates? I used to do this all the time, and if you scroll months (say, to check a date in September) and then accidentally hit OK instead of Cancel - you overwrite the system time. Luckly, Win7 changed the behaviour so you can click the clock to get a read-only calendar up.

Comment: D'oh! its always the simplest thing!

Comment: Hehe, I used to do that every few months when using XP, and it's a real pain when the tidal wave of reminders and warnings from various programs hits you. I'll upgrade my comment to an answer, wasn't really expecting it to be useful otherwise it would of started there! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't happen to double-click the clock to get the calendar up to check on dates?

I used to do this all the time, and if you scroll months (say, to check a date in September) and then accidentally hit OK instead of Cancel - you overwrite the system time.

Luckly, Win7 changed the behaviour so you can click the clock to get a read-only calendar up.

Comment: It used to be worse. Windows 95/98 would change the system clock [as soon as you flipped months](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/21/431054.aspx), without even clicking OK or Apply.